# Having issue with the “for” statement or maybe confusion on how to correctly implement the statement.

Tags: javascript

What I’m trying to build Math testing app with JavaScript.  But I’m having an issue with the FOR statement, what I want it to do is to add one point to the score for every question answered correct. To test it I have set the score to 0 and userID would be user input, if user enters the correct answer it would increase to 1 but it keeps increasing to 10. Is there a way to stop the count after the first cycle and wait till the second cycle and so forth till it hits 10?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="scoreBlock"><span id="score">0</span></div>
<input type="text" id="userID"/>
<button onclick="begin();">Start</button>



<script>
function begin(){

var h= document.getElementById("score");
var user =document.getElementById("userID").value;
var test = "5";

for(h=0;h<=10;h++){
if(user==="5"){

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= h;

}else if(!user==="5"){

alert("noting");
}

}//end of while
}//end of function
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this test you consider the right answer happens when user == 5. You do it 10 times while not changing the conditions. So obviously it's 10 time the right answer.

```
<script>
function begin(){

var user = document.getElementById("userID").value;
var test = "5";
var correctAnswer = 0;

for(var h=0;h<=10;h++){
    if(user==="5"){
        correctAnswer++;
    }
}

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= correctAnswer;

if (correctAnswer == 0) {
    alert("noting");
}
</script>
```

Comment: function begin(){
    var score = 0; 
    var numb1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var numb2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var user = document.getElementById("userID").value;
    var answer = +numb1 * +numb2;
    alert(answer);
    if(user == answer) {
    score++;
    }
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= score;
    }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the score to be updated every time the user clicks the button and checks if the value of user is the same as test. In that case, you don't need a For loop.

```
<script>
var score = 0; 
var test = "5";

function begin(){
  var user = document.getElementById("userID").value;
  if(user === test) {
    score++;
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= score;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it and it work, so i added two inputs "num1","num2" and create a varable var answer = +num1 * +num2 and replaced the test with answer so if user answered it correctly it would increase to 1 which it did but i tryed again it would only show "1" as the score

Comment: Try putting your code on jsfiddle so we can see what's going on.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/2Xcjp/10/ . I moved the initialization of score outside the function so it does not get reinitialized every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes!! that is how i want it to work, thanks i've been working on it for a week .